# Can't acess object attribute outside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new with React Js or any kind of javascript framework. I created a "allServices" var outside the "onLoadServices", inside it a pass a data to it, as you can see below. The problem is, when I console.log it inside de const onLoadService, it shows me the entire object and I also can access the attributes, but outside it just shows me the entire object, but when a try to access the atributes it fails

```
    let allServices = {
  id: '',
  client_id: '',
  user_id: '',
  status: "",
  repair_value: "",
  taxes: "",
  service_code: "",
  has_client_paid: "",
  has_technician_paid: "",
  plate: "",
  brand: "",
  model: "",
  year: "",
  color: "",
  created_at: "",
  updated_at: ""
};
const Dashboard = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const [technicians, setTechnicians] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoadSerivces();
    onLoadTechnicians();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
  }, [filters]);

  const onLoadSerivces = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await api.get(`/service`);
      allServices = response.data.data
      console.log("first log  ", allServices[0])
    }
    catch (err) {
      let error = JSON.stringify(err.message);
      alert(error);
    }
  };
  console.log("Second log ", allServices[0])
```

If I try to print the object without[0] it shows me the samething in both console.logs... the problem is with the atributtes.

The error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined"

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where do you use `onLoadServices`? as its `async`, program will continue execution and do `console.log` before retrieving results

Comment: I don't see call of function `onLoadServices`. You have to use `await` or `then` to work with async code

Comment: I just use onLoadServices just to get the data from de api. But, why console.log shows me the entire object then?

Comment: I didn't get the await or then thing, I am using it wrong? Because it I have await in code

Comment: I think you are destructuring the data and calling it again for data.data.     Whats the expected output from api.get('/service'). I think from there we can easily figure out whats going on.

Comment: the "await" is a syntactic sugar for promises to skip another `.then()` block and get the expected value

Comment: The expected output is a object value, if a take out the allServices[0].status, and replace with allServices[0] it shows me the object with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything right. When you logging in your "second Console.log" the value is not assigned to your variable just yet since you set it inside of the asynchronous function. If you are using this variable anywhere in the code, just check if it is set already before accessing properties inside of it.

Edit1:
Not sure if that's the case, and what kind of response you are getting, but maybe try to convert it to json, and see if it makes a difference.

```
const response = await api.get(`/service`);
const data = await response.json();
```

Edit2:
I think I understood what's happening:) when you are logging in object second time it is NOT set yet, so when you are trying to access the value - you get an error. The reason why you see it when loggin in the object itself - is because you print the reference to the object, so if it's allocated a few millseconds later it's still getting printed.

If you print it without the reference second time, most likely it still be empty, try: 
`console.log("second Console.log ", Object.assign({}, allServices))`

Edit3
To see if you are setting value try doing something like this, just to see if you are able to use it

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [allServices, setAllServices] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoadSerivces();
  }, []);


  const onLoadSerivces = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await api.get('/service');
      const result = response.data.data;
      console.log('first log  ', result[0]);
      setAllServices(result);
    } catch (err) {
      const error = JSON.stringify(err.message);
      alert(error);
    }
  };


  // assume this will be an array
  render() {
    return allServices && allServices.map(service => {
      console.log('Second log ', service);
      return <div>{service.status}</div>;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I see, but if a take out the allServices[0].status, and replace with allServices[0] it shows me the object with data,

Comment: I get a object as response, your sugestion unhappyly didn't work

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, I tried what you said and the result still the entire object. I also tried to populed the objet when I first created it and it also keep falling. Maybe it the async thing? If I transform it into a callable function it could work?

Comment: when you say `I get an object as response` what do you mean ? Isn't it the right object ?

Comment: I'm just curious to see when you are actually calling this function? I would assume on component mount or in useEffect? if so - set that variable in state and add logic that uses this variable since it is certainly set and you are able to print it inside of the function call.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code along with a render part. So far, I still think you aren't doing anything wrong, Printing that variable on same level as the async function you are calling might be throwing you off.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it with useEffect, I will try to set the state

Comment: I put more parts of parts of the code, see if it is what you asked

Comment: Sorry, fu7zed. I didn't understand your question

Comment: How do I " set that variable in state" ? What I search to learn that?

Comment: Thanks! Your sugestion didn't work the way I needed, but helped me find a solution